# What is this about going back to the future?

Tags: support

I was browsing the site a while ago and it looked kinda strange.

[image: Oh the nostalgia]

To complete the visual offense, the "welcome to stackoverflow" bit seemed to be a marquee.

What is this?

Comment: Check the calendar (anywhere in the world).

Comment: @MonicaCellio I can't believe I fell for that. Thanks!

Comment: Needs more <blink>

Comment: Ugh... the 90s... a company I worked for had a (gratefully) internal web site that was dark blue text on a burnt orange background.